# Thrift cross compiling for ARM

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, thrift, configure, libcrypto

I have configured and installed thrift package in my Linux machine. Now am trying to cross compile thrift for ARM.

The steps I followed are :

1. Untar the thrift package
2. Configure using `./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --without-java --without-python --with-c_glib --with-cpp` 
   But when I am doing this, I get the following error

> ```
> checking for boostlib >= 1.54.0... yes
> checking for libevent >= 1.0... configure: error: in '/home/deeraj/arm_thrift':
> configure: error: cannot run test program while cross compiling
> See 'config.log' for more details
> ```

To over come this, I replaced `AC_RUN_IFELSE` with `AC_LINK_IFELSE` in the files `aclocal/ax_lib_event.m4` and `aclocal/ax_lib_zlib.m4`. After this, I ran the `autoconf`

When I ran the `./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --without-java --without-python --with-c_glib --with-cpp` again, I got the following error :

```
checking for setsockopt in -lsocket... no
checking for BN_init in -lcrypto... no
configure: error: "Error: libcrypto required."
```

I have already installed `libssl-dev`, but its not removing the error.

How can we solve this issue and cross compile and install thrift for ARM?

Comment: By "installed libssl-dev", do you mean that you've configured and built a suitable `libcrypto.so` _with the cross-compiler_, or just dumped its source files in a directory somewhere? The latter is insufficient ;)

Comment: I installed using the command `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`. I have seen in other posts that, this is supposed to solve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried asking this on the mailing list? Or freenode?

Comment: No I have not. Going to ask in the mailing list

Comment: The libssl-dev package is meant for installing libcrypto.so for direct use on your host system. Since you are cross compiling, you will need to build and provide a reference to libcrypto (and its header files) that is compiled for the target platform.